# Why does the following C code output 1?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
union p
{
    int x;
    char y;
} k = {1, 97};
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", k.y);
}
```

Here is the code. When I replace that 97 with 67 output is 1. How does that `1` get printed?

Comment: You’re using the wrong format specifier.

Comment: You can only specify 1 initializer for `k` — what you show should not compile.  Without a specific designation (designated initializer), it initializes the first member defined, `x`.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: No — since the character is converted to an `int` under default argument promotion rules, `%d` is perfectly OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I don't think excessive initializers violate a constraint?  AFAIK they're just ignored.

Comment: Live and learn, didn’t know it happened in this situation also.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: With GCC (`gcc -O3   -g         -std=c11   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes         union41.c -o union41`), I get: `union41.c:7:11: error: excess elements in union initializer [-Werror]
 } k = {1, 97};`.  That is a warning converted to error by `-Werror`.  If you have too many initializers for a structure, you get a warning from GCC too.  I get the warning without any prompting (`gcc -c union41.c`).  I don't compile without `-Werror` too (or, only very, very seldom) so it counts as an error for me.  I'm surprised it isn't a constraint violation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler alright ;) Well, I don't see a good reason to allow them either. But obviously they are allowed. About `-Werror`, that's a question of personal workflow -- if you always watch out for any warnings (I do that), I don't see a reason to enable `-Werror`. Without it, I can see further warnings in one step ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Doesn't §6.7.9 Initialization ¶2 apply: _No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity
being initialized._  There isn't an element for the excess initializer to  apply to.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Interestingly, designated initializers remove the warnings: `union r
{
    int x;
    char y;
} r = { .x = 1, .y = 97 };` compiles without warning.  The last listed initializer prevails.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler after re-reading the whole §6.7, It's not exactly specified. It says that each initializer has an associated current object and how to find that object in absence of a designator, but if I just have an excess initializer (without designator), I can't associate an object. I guess the standard could be more explicit here, but it seems compilers interpret it as "*an object not contained within the entity being initialized*" could only be associated by a designator.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler as for providing "redundant" `union` initializers by designation, this is indeed exactly specified. The standard even says that the overridden initializer might not be evaluated at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes it is a constraint violation, because it asks to initialize the "next" member after the union member, which obviously doesn't exist. But the only required action for that is a diagnostic. In the case of the designated initializers it isn't a violation, because it explicitly states which members are to be initialized.

Comment: @Jens (and Felix): I was not expecting any complaint with designated initializers — that was more for 'other readers'.  Footnote 149 is also apposite, I think: _149) After a union member is initialized, the next object is not the next member of the union; instead, it is
the next subobject of an object containing the union._  In this case, there is no next subobject.  I understand that a diagnostic is all that's required, and that's all GCC gives unless you specify `-Werror`.  I wonder if the OP's compiler gave a warning?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and Jens, interesting, if it's indeed a constraint violation, a compiler **must** generate this warning. I don't think the text is absolutely clear in this regard (see above), but I would also interpret it that way. In that case, maybe we should just suggest "*have a look at the console output of your compiler*"? :o

Answer (score 7):

Your compiler should actually warn you about "excessive initializers" or something similar. Try to enable more warnings (personal recommendation for `gcc`/`clang`: `-std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`).

With a `union`, an initializer (without a designator) always initializes the first union member. You can't have multiple members of a `union` hold a value at the same time, they all share the same memory, so initializing more than one doesn't make sense. If you do using designators, the last one "wins".

Your compiler just drops the `97` and uses the `1` for initializing `p.x`. This doesn't guarantee reading `p.y` will give you `1`, but on a little-endian machine, this will happen.

Comment: Note that GCC (7.2.0 at any rate) warns about the excess initializers even with no warning-provoking options (`gcc -c union41.c`, for example).

Answer (score 3):

Because a `union`, other than a `struct`, overlays its members. It makes no sense to initialize both members.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is undefined - you can only initialize one of the members of a union because all members occupy are stored at the same address.   I am surprised your C compiler didn’t get all excited about this, have you disabled warnings?  Once you have jumped into undefined, there is no telling what the compiler will do.

Comment: The program isn't undefined.

Comment: It's not technically undefined, but it is very bad coding practice.  Depending on the endieness of the system, the 1 will either be stored in the high or low address of a (likely) four byte memory region.   The char will always be read from the lowest byte, so the behavior of the program will depend on what processor it's running on.

Comment: [link]{http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization} paragraph 5-7 says ‘must’, thus not valid program.  The undefined bit is about which initializer the compiler chooses, not the endianness of the interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is an union and only one initialisation value is needed. The second one is ignored.